# Bitmap : Set Wallpaper and Save on Sdcard in Menu Item

Tags: android, bitmap

i almost finished my app, im working on menu items now, 
The problem is to set a bitmap as wallpaper and save it on sdcard from menu item.

i tried to things, 1st was to create a second intent which was taking -again- same data from previous activity , -I have failed-

2nd was using the same intent -i ve failed-

here is my code.

thank you

```
public class Fullpic  extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_pics, menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {

        case R.id.menu_set:

          // setting as wallpaper
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_save:

           // save the image on sdcard

            return true;


        case R.id.menu_back:

            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

     //menu end


    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "source";
    static final String HEIGHT_MAX = "600";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_pic);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get XML values from previous intent dude
        String bid = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
        int hoppa= Integer.parseInt(in.getStringExtra(HEIGHT_MAX));

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        ImageView balls = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bals_label);
        balls.getLayoutParams().height = hoppa-30;



        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(bid);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        balls.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }


    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,
    IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }  
    private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "source");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure as to which aspect you are having difficulties, if it is just to save the image after downloading you can create a new file from the InputStream you created when making the Drawable and save it to the location required.

Comment: @kabuto178 would you help me, please ? i really can't

Comment: Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: @kabuto178 3 mins before i did i think. Can you check the code please, is it as u said to me ? or is there better way ? it s freezing for a while when i click on button. because it takes all values again as you can see.. thank you again  http://pastebin.com/AwbrAkn8

Comment: Nice work there in that pastebin link you posted, now all you need to do is put it in a thread `new Thread(new Runnable(....code here....)).start();` and that should help with the lag when you click :)

Comment: @kabuto178 thank you. you showed me the way.. post it if you want then i ll check ur msg as accepted answer, then u may get some rep if you want, this is the only thing that i can do for you :) thank you again. :)

Comment: Your welcome, the code you have in pastebin is exactly what I was going to suggest to you ^_^, will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
           String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/blabla");    
                myDir.mkdirs();

                String fname = "name_here.jpg";
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists ()) 
                     file.delete ();
                try {
                       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); //create stream to output the contents of the image
                       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); //compress and write bitmap data to output file stream
                       out.flush();
                       out.close(); //closes stream important to avoid memory leaks

                } catch (Exception e) {
                      //exception handling
                }
           }}).start();
```

This should help you write the bitmap file to where you need it to be on the SD card of the device, and done in a thread to keep heavy actions off the main UI Thread. Cheers.